# writing to file in maven project

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

Hi i am using maven web project and want to write something to file abc.properties. This file in placed in standard /src/main/resource folder. My code is:

```
FileWriter file = new FileWriter("./src/main/resources/abc.properties");
            try {
                file.write("hi i am good");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {
                file.flush();
                file.close();
            }
```

But it does not work as path is not correct. I tried many other examples but was unable to give path of this file.

Can you kindly help me in setting path of file which is placed in resources folder.

Thanks

Comment: /src/main/resources is maven's conventional path for resource files you want to add in your classpath at runtime. when you create jar/war from maven project using maven commands, this directory will not be there. maven will put all resources from this directory to classpath of your generated artifact.

Comment: you want file to be dynamically generated from program or just wants it to be copied at classpath?

Comment: At run time i will be writing something to this file and will read it as well

Comment: have you tried giving only file name without any path? i think it should do

Comment: Yeah i tried /abc.properties but it didnt worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60757/discussion-between-adi-and-mr37037).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing buildtime and runtime. During buildtime you have your `src/main/java`, `src/main/resources` and `src/main/webapp`, but during runtime these are all bundled in a war-file. This means there's no such thing as `src/main/resources` anymore.
The easiest way is to write to a [tempFile][1] and write to that file. The best way is to configure your outputFile, for instance in the `wqeb.xml`.

[1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: Can you kindly elaborate your point? With some coding Example?

Comment: File file = File.createTempFile("abc-", ".properties");
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

Answer (score 0):

If your file is dropped under *src/main/resources*, it will end up under *your-webapp/WEB-INF/classes* directory if you project is package as a Web application i.e. with *maven-war-plugin*.

At runtime, if you want to files that are located under the latter directory, which are considered as web application resources, thus are already present in the application classpath, you can use the `getResourceAsStream()` method either on the `ServletContext` or using the current class `ClassLoader`:

*From current thread context:*

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("abc.properties");
FileWriter file = new FileWriter(new File(new FileInputStream(is)));
// some funny stuff goes here
```

*If you have access to the Servlet context:*

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
InputStream is = context.getResourceAsStream("/abc.properties");
FileWriter file = new FileWriter(new File(new FileInputStream(is)));
// some funny stuff goes here
```

**Notice the leading slash in the latter example.**

Comment: File can't find constructor that accepts FileInputStream

Comment: FileInputStream can't find constructor that accepts InputStream

Comment: This doesn't work.    
FileInputStream can't find constructor that accepts InputStream